# Find the coordinates of mid point of 4 coordinates in R

Tags: r, geolocation, coordinates, latitude-longitude, centroid

First thanks for all the help I get from all of you on my previous questions.

I tried to look for a function that can find the centre coordinates for my dataset below:

```
df <- read.table(sep=",", col.names=c("Start_Latitude","Start_Longitude","End_Latitude", "End_Longitude"),text="43.9567343,  -78.8571382, 43.9399364, -78.8497342")

Start_Latitude    Start_Longitude   End_Latitude    End_Longitude      
  43.9567343       -78.8571382       43.9399364      -78.8497342
```

I tried this code but it only calculates the distance from the starting coordinates to the ending coordinates, and I want to find the mid point coordinates not only the distance. I mean I need to find the long and lat of the mid point.

```
#dd the distance as column in the dataframe
df1$dist <- distm(x = df[, c('Start_Longitude', 'Start_Longitude')], 
                y = df[, c('End_Longitude', 'End_Latitude')],
                fun = distHaversine
)
```

And I had this dataset:

```
 Start_Latitude    Start_Longitude   End_Latitude    End_Longitude       dist
      43.9567343       -78.8571382       43.9399364      -78.8497342     13669708
```

Is there anyway to find the lat and the long of the mid point? Also, how can I calculate the distance in kilometre.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with `geosphere::midPoint`:

```
library(geosphere)
data.frame(df,
           dist = distHaversine(df[, c('Start_Longitude', 'Start_Latitude')],
                                df[, c('End_Longitude', 'End_Latitude')]) / 1000, 
           midPoint(p1 = df[, c('Start_Longitude', 'Start_Latitude')],
                    p2 = df[, c('End_Longitude', 'End_Latitude')]))
#  Start_Latitude Start_Longitude End_Latitude End_Longitude    dist       lon      lat
#1       43.95673       -78.85714     43.93994     -78.84973 1.96183 -78.85344 43.94834
```

Comment: I was wondering why your first post of this answer had results for `lat` and `long` that were so different than my answer. What happened between first & second iterations of your answer?

Comment: @LenGreski I made the mistake of copying the OP's code. They have the start coordinates repeated.

Comment: The SO system works. The discrepancy got both of us to double check our answers. Upvoted.

Comment: Indeed it does. I also learned how little difference the curvature of the Earth makes at short distances.

Answer (score 2):

One can calculate the midpoints by averaging the lat / long combinations. Using data from the original post, we use `dplyr::mutate()` to calculate the midpoint.

```
textFile <- "Start_Latitude    Start_Longitude   End_Latitude    End_Longitude      
  43.9567343       -78.8571382       43.9399364      -78.8497342
41.947460   -87.654730   41.890620   -87.624480"

data <- read.table(text=textFile,header=TRUE)

library(dplyr)
data %>% rowwise(.) %>% 
    mutate(midpoint_lat = sum(Start_Latitude,End_Latitude)/2,
           midpoint_long = sum(Start_Longitude,End_Longitude)/2) %>%
    as.data.frame(.) # print as df, not tibble
```

...and the output:

```
  Start_Latitude Start_Longitude End_Latitude End_Longitude id midpoint_lat
1       43.95673       -78.85714     43.93994     -78.84973  1     43.94834
2       41.94746       -87.65473     41.89062     -87.62448  2     41.91904
  midpoint_long
1     -78.85344
2     -87.63961
```

### Calculating distance in kilometres

As explained in the help for the [distHaversine()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geosphere/versions/1.5-10/topics/distHaversine) function from the [geosphere](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geosphere/geosphere.pdf) package, the unit of measure in the result is returned based on the argument given for the radius of the earth. The default value is `r = 6378137` metres, so the unit of measure is returned in meters.

To convert to kilometres, one has two choices:

1. Divide the result by 1,000 (as illustrated in the other answer to this question), or
2. Change the argument `r` to 6378.137

Comment: One limitation of this approach is that it does not consider the curvature of the earth. Of course, if high levels of accuracy are not required, this would be fine.

Comment: In fact, the two approaches only differ 4.2cm in this example.

Comment: @IanCampbell - Understood. On google maps, these coordinates are about 650 meters apart, or metres since the locations are in Ontario, Canada.

Comment: I tried Len Greski answer but when the run the command :  data %>% mutate(midpoint_lat = sum(Start_Latitude,End_Latitude)/2,
                midpoint_long = sum(Start_Longitude,End_Longitude)/2)  it gives different midpoint lat and long ... I got midpoint lat : 8525.977 and the midpoint long  -15297.57 .. BTW , I didn't change the data frame into table because I keep getting error message

Comment: @Reta - looks like the `sum()` function in `mutate()` is aggregating across rows. I'll update my solution to mitigate this.

Comment: @Reta - I added `rowwise()` to stop `mutate()` from aggregating across rows. Now the dplyr pipeline will calculate midpoints for data frames that contain multiple observations.